# House of Cards - how realistic?

Tags: linux, windows, cross-platform, theory, virus

I have finished watching the 2nd season of House of Cards, and I'm appalled. The show really is fantastic, however let me get down straight to the point - computer-wise, how realistic is the show? Gavin Orsay, a hacker and informant for the FBI created a USB stick for the *The Washington Herald* reporter Lucas Goodwin, which contained malicious code that would be automatically injected into any machine when plugged in.

- Theoretically, is this possible?

Not that I would want to do something like that, I'm just interested... And I'm not talking about `autorun.inf`s, I mean real code that would be able to penetrate into a system, a virus, essentially. And if there was to be such a virus, would it be able to inject itself cross-platform? i.e. do the same amount of damage both on Windows, Unix, Linux distros etc.

Comment: This probably belongs to [security.SE]

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not only possible it has been done many times. have a look at the Stuxnex virus developed by the United States to slow down Iran's uranium enrichment program.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuxnet

As far as cross platform, the flash drive could have different versions of the same virus/trojan/worm compiled for different hardware and operating systems. Developing software like this is not a matter of "if" it can be done, it is a matter of how much time/money do you have to make it happen!

Comment: Stuxnet was Windows-only specific, so comparing them with question is bad. Also again, what if USB ports are disabled, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible. There have been certain countermeasures that have been implemented in Unix systems that pride themselves on being safe from attacks such as these.

That said, it wouldn't work on **every machine**.

Comment: And if i disable USB ports?

Comment: If you disable a USB port at the BIOS level, then I don't see how the data could ever be read from the USB drive. I'm fairly sure the power to the port is even disabled at that point, though it could depend on the motherboard.